# simplify simple query sql

Tags: sql, firebird

Can someone help me simplify the following query into one line .

```
SELECT 
  LL_ID, 
  LL_VOORNAAM, 
  LB_VAN_VAN, 
  LB_VAN_TOT, 
  LB_VAN_ID, 
  LB_VAN_INUIT_FK, 
  LB_NAAR_INUIT_FK, 
  iu_vorigeinuit_fk, 
  iu_id, 
  LB_NAAR_ID, 
  LB_NAAR_VAN, 
  LB_NAAR_TOT 
FROM 
  LEERLING 
  INNER JOIN INUIT ON (LL_ID = IU_LEERLING_FK) 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      LB_ID AS LB_VAN_ID, 
      LB_VAN AS LB_VAN_VAN, 
      LB_TOT AS LB_VAN_TOT, 
      LB_INUIT_FK AS LB_VAN_INUIT_FK 
    FROM 
      LOOPBAAN
  ) AS LOOPBAAN_VAN ON (
    (IU_ID = LB_VAN_INUIT_FK)
  ) 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      LB_ID AS LB_NAAR_ID, 
      LB_VAN AS LB_NAAR_VAN, 
      LB_TOT AS LB_NAAR_TOT, 
      LB_INUIT_FK AS LB_NAAR_INUIT_FK 
    FROM 
      LOOPBAAN
  ) AS LOOPBAAN_NAAR ON (
    (iu_id = LB_NAAR_INUIT_FK)
  ) 
WHERE 
  (LB_VAN_ID <> LB_NAAR_ID) 
  AND (
    LB_NAAR_VAN = DATEADD(1 DAY TO LB_VAN_TOT)
  ) 
  and LL_ID in (41366) 
order by 
  ll_naam
```

Currently, I'm getting three repeated values which I want to merge into one. See the result I would like to have.

note : "Van" means From and "naar" To
[image]

Comment: Please post data as text not images.

Comment: I would suggest to read up on group by, min/max etc to help here.  You dont state the logic in the image, so not sure how it's condensed by max values min values earliest date etc.

Comment: Why is this tagged MySQL and Firebird? Please only tag one DBMS.

Comment: Please create all the sample tables with all the needed data and sample queries in http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=firebird_3.0 so everyone, us and you, could test their queries and their results

Comment: Although creating a Fiddle is helpful, you need to provide a [mre] (including DDL and DML to setup test data) in the question itself.

Comment: Correct. And bonus: dbFiddle can produce Markdown export, that can be copy-pasted into the question here.

Answer (score 0):

This did it for me...
`) AS LOOPBAAN_VAN ON ((IU_VORIGEINUIT_FK = LB_VAN_INUIT_FK) )`

```
SELECT 
  LL_ID, 
  LL_VOORNAAM, 
  LB_VAN_VAN, 
  LB_VAN_TOT, 
  LB_VAN_ID, 
  LB_VAN_INUIT_FK, 
  LB_NAAR_INUIT_FK,
  iu_vorigeinuit_fk,
  iu_id,
  LB_NAAR_ID,
  LB_NAAR_VAN, 
  LB_NAAR_TOT
FROM 
  LEERLING 
  INNER JOIN INUIT ON (LL_ID = IU_LEERLING_FK) 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      LB_ID AS LB_VAN_ID, 
      LB_VAN AS LB_VAN_VAN, 
      LB_TOT AS LB_VAN_TOT, 
      LB_INUIT_FK AS LB_VAN_INUIT_FK 
    FROM 
      LOOPBAAN 
  ) AS LOOPBAAN_VAN ON ((IU_VORIGEINUIT_FK = LB_VAN_INUIT_FK) ) 
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
      LB_ID AS LB_NAAR_ID, 
      LB_VAN AS LB_NAAR_VAN, 
      LB_TOT AS LB_NAAR_TOT, 
      LB_INUIT_FK AS LB_NAAR_INUIT_FK
    FROM 
      LOOPBAAN 
  ) AS LOOPBAAN_NAAR ON (( iu_id = LB_NAAR_INUIT_FK))
WHERE 
  (LB_VAN_ID <> LB_NAAR_ID) 
 AND (
   LB_NAAR_VAN = DATEADD(1 DAY TO LB_VAN_TOT)  ) 
and
  LL_ID in (41366)
order by ll_naam
```